# Use PHP session variable array in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get the `seat_number` from my table named `flight_Seat_Status` but i am using a while loop because i have multiple users to display with their flight info.

first i start my loop

```
while($count < $_SESSION['passengers']){
```

then i echo the results in a table

```
echo "<tr> <td>".$_SESSION['firstname'][$count]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$_SESSION['lastname'][$count]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$_SESSION['from']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$_SESSION['destination'][$count]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$_SESSION['departureseat'][$count]."</td>";//get seat number $count++; }
```

what im trying to do is

```
  $query = ($conn,"SELECT * from flight_seat_status where seat_id = '$_SESSION[departureseat][$count]'")
```

departureseat contains the seat_id where i want to find the seat_number of that seat_id.

Comment: Whats the issue that you are facing?

Comment: well i want to know how to fetch data from the database using php array variables

Comment: Is your code causing some issue?

Comment: @TheAsker101 Accessing the element from the array and pass that in as a parameter to your query. It look's like you already did that.

Comment: My code does not work at all. should i save the element from the array in a variable before using it in my select statement?

Comment: `$query = ($conn, "...")` is meaningless junk. Are you forgetting to prepare your query properly?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user-supplied data might be used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Variable parsing](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> There are two types of syntax: a [simple](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) one and a [complex](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) one.

Then, under [Simple syntax](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple):

> With array indices, the closing square bracket (]) marks the end of the index.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> For anything more complex, you should use the complex syntax.

Whereas, under [Complex (curly) syntax](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> ```
> // Works. When using multi-dimensional arrays, always use braces around arrays
> // when inside of strings
> echo "This works: {$arr['foo'][3]}";
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Read the PHP documentation on [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). In order to interpolate an array element with a variable index into a string, you have to use the "complex" syntax where you wrap it with curly braces.

```
$query = ($conn,"SELECT * from flight_seat_status where seat_id = '{$_SESSION['departureseat'][$count]}'")
```

BTW, I recommend you refactor your session variable. Instead of having separate arrays for each property like `firstname`, `lastname`, `departureseat`, make it an array of associative arrays.

```
$_SESSION['passengers'][$passengerid] = array(
    'passengerid' => $passengerid,
    'firstname' => "John",
    'lastname' => "Smith",
    'destination' => "BOS",
    ...
);
```

This will allow you to use `foreach ($_SESSION['passengers'] AS $p)`.